# PHPUnit can't generate code coverage when running tests in separate processes

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, xdebug

I have a problem that I could not find the solution on Google.
When I run my unit tests with PHPUnit and Xdebug, I would like to do a code coverage.

However, when I do that, I get this error:

```sh
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Fatal error: Uncaught SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\NoCodeCoverageDriverAvailableException: No code coverage driver available in /Users/theobenoit/Desktop/Antipode.nosync/Sites/wp-framework-core/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/Driver/Selector.php:53
   ├ Stack trace:
   ├ #0 Standard input code(43): SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Driver\Selector->forLineCoverage(Object(SebastianBergmann\CodeCoverage\Filter))
   ├ #1 Standard input code(123): __phpunit_run_isolated_test()
   ├ #2 {main}
   ├   thrown in /Users/theobenoit/Desktop/Antipode.nosync/Sites/wp-framework-core/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/src/Driver/Selector.php on line 53
```

I realized that this is because in some of my tests there is this at the top:

```php
/**
 * @runTestsInSeparateProcesses
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

When I remove `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` everything works fine, but there are problems because I mock functions.

If anyone has ever had this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because with `runTestsInSeparateProcesses`, PHPUnit starts a new PHP process for every test. And it seems that it does that without Xdebug loaded.

The PHP that is started for each test needs to be the same as the one that you originally started PHPUnit with. Perhaps there is a different PHP binary first in the PATH?

If that is the case, the way to solve it is to make sure the "right" PHP is first in the `PATH`.

Comment: Hello @Derick, thanks for your answer. Yes you might be right. It might be because PHP is not the same.
When i run php -v I have the php with xDebug, but when i run which php, i get the path to the php, and this php -v doesn't have xDebug. 

php: aliased to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.9/bin/php -c "/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php7.4.9.ini"

Comment: By the way, If i just run ./vendor/bin/phpunit I have "no code driver" but If i do php ./vendor/bin/phpunit it's fine. It may come from here

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the very same problem by disabling force break when there are no mappings, a setting in the IDE under xdebug-settings.

See:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009770579-Docker-debug-problem-Remote-file-path-home-www-Standard-input-code-is-not-mapped-to-any-file-path-in-project-